# LWP::UserAgent proxy in Perl session

Tags: perl, shell, proxy, terminal, lwp-useragent

I need to change the proxy server in one Perl run (process). But [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent) is always remembering the *first* proxy value.

When I start my program with proxy `x.x.x.2`, this address is always used as proxy.

What is wrong?

The simple program Example:

```
getHTTP('http://my.com/', "http://x.x.x.1:3128");
getHTTP('http://my.com/', "http://x.x.x.2:3128");
getHTTP('http://my.com/', "");
getHTTP('http://my.com/', "http://x.x.x.3:3128");

sub getHTTP {
    my ($url, $proxy) = @_;
    use LWP::UserAgent;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->proxy(http => $proxy);
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    return $ua->request($req)->as_string;
}
```

Output from HTTP log:

```
x.x.x.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:28:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3467
x.x.x.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:29:07 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3467
y.y.y.y - - [09/Feb/2015:15:29:08 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3467
x.x.x.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:29:09 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3467
```

(*y.y.y.y is my no proxy address*)

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7

**NEW findings:**
When I run next perl or shell scripts. The same result as above.

proxy.sh:

```
curl -x "http://x.x.x.1:3128" http://my.com/
curl -x "http://x.x.x.2:3128" http://my.com/
curl -x "http://x.x.x.3:3128" http://my.com/
```

*Result: always x.x.x.1 proxy*

proxy.pl:

```
`curl -x "http://x.x.x.4:3128" http://my.com/`;
`curl -x "http://x.x.x.5:3128" http://my.com/`;
`curl -x "http://x.x.x.6:3128" http://my.com/`;
```

*Result: always x.x.x.4 proxy*

It looks like the proxy settings cannot change in one shell process.

Comment: This looks fine. Is it different from the actual code that you are running?

Comment: (My original code is much more complicated.) But when I run this simple example, the output is the same. In other words, this simple program causes described behavior.

Comment: Could it be due to proxy configuration? Are the proxies connected somehow to do load balancing or can they select which interface is used?

Comment: I don't think so. Please see on my new findings!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what's going on here, exactly, and in fact I think you may have found a bug in LWP (if what you're showing us is what you're actually executing). However, is there a reason why you're building the GET request from HTTP::Request instead of directly through the User Agent object? In other words, instead of doing this:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
return $ua->request($req)->as_string;
```

Do this:

```
my $res = $ua->get($url);
return $res->as_string;
```

In theory, the two methods should be equivalent, but I wonder if the proxy settings aren't correctly propagating to HTTP::Request when you do it this way.

Comment: In my simple example is no reason to use HTTP::Request.

Comment: When I changed code to your suggestion, output is the same.